# find pixels in stack with same sign?

Tags: r

0

I have these rasters:

```
 library(raster)
 r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
 r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1))
 r2[] <- runif(ncell(r2)) / 2
 r3[] <- runif(ncell(r3)) * 1.5
 s <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
```

I need to produce a map with three colors:

red  all 3 pixels are negative

green  all 3 pixels are positive

black the 3 pixels are mix negative and positive

Any idea on this?

Comment: You can try using `mtx <- sapply(as.list(s), function(x) x@data@values)` and
`apply(mtx, 1, function(x) ifelse(all(x>0),"green", ifelse(all(x<0),"red","black")))`

Comment: thanks but how to plot then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data (changed so that it has negative and positive values)

```
library(raster)
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
set.seed(1)
r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1))
r2[] <- runif(ncell(r2))
r3[] <- runif(ncell(r3))
s <- stack(r1, r2, r3) - 0.5
```

Solution --- note that this works because trunc goes towards zero for both positive and negative numbers

```
x <- trunc(mean(sign(s)))
```

And you can plot it like this

```
plot(x, col=c("red", "black", "green"))
```